# Magento REST api

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth

I am trying to use magento rest api for customers. But when i authenticate the application, it gives me following error.

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
Service temporary unavailable
```

I am trying to fetch product collection for customer role.

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml'));
```

The line of code throws exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried adding an "Accept" header to your request? I ran into the same problem with the Magento API, tested it and found that the PHP OAuth client doesn't send any accept header by default. So try the following instead:

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'Accept' => 'application/xml'));
```

or

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
```

You can view more info about the exception by using the following when you set up the client:

```
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
```

...and then looking at the debug with:

```
$oauthClient->debugInfo
```

or

```
$oauthClient->getLastResponse
```

The other methods are documented here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php

Comment: $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'Accept' => '*/*'));

This works, and solved the problem..

Comment: Works for me too Hasina

Answer (score 2):

I've used        `$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));` which works fine.